# Transform alpha-numeric strings to int value

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to transform strings of any size to an integer.
For example: "a" - 01; "b" - 02; "c" - 03; "ab" - 0102; "aac" - 010103.

Right now, I am replacing every single char in the string with a value from an array.
Is there a simple, more fancy way to do this?

Comment: "I am looking for a way to transform strings of any size to an integer." - How about `"any string whatsoever 1234".GetHashCode()`? Or what are your **exact** rules? What do you want to achieve? Note, that `010103` is a "weird" way of writing the integer `10103`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> more fancy

```cs
string source = "aac";

string result_string = string.Join("", source.Select(c => (c - 'a' + 1).ToString("00")));
```

```cs
string source = "aac";

int result_int = source.Select(c => (c - 'a' + 1)).Aggregate((a, i) => a * 100 + i);
```

Comment: Doesn't really work for strings that contain numbers e.g. "aa9"

Comment: You never gave any sufficient rules for the conversion. This is code optimized for fanciness as requested, not for usefulness.

Comment: You are right. I will try to make it by myself then(I have no idea how) :/ Thanks anyway! Still useful!